# Domain Object Validation in play

Tags: scala, validation, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to implement some domain object validation in Play 2 with scala in my REST based project. For the same project which was a in java earlier we use oval for that purpose. Any one can help me out by any such kind of validation tool to work with case class or at the JSON conversion. Any thing do we have in play framework to do this kind of domain object validation. 
Any help will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

Check out play json framework:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson

It is a very powerful framework for validating JSON objects